# How to edit console line above current with Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, stdout, ansi-escape

Currently, I am editing a single line.

```
const editLine = (data) => {
  process.stdout.clearLine();
  process.stdout.write(`\r${data}`);
};

// Call editLine() whenever there is new data to log on that line
```

Suppose we have a function like this one. It edits whatever line the cursor is currently on. However, let's say we do something like this...

```
console.log('Hi');
console.log('There');
```

Is there any way I could edit the line that says "Hi"? Currently, I am only aware of ways to edit the current line with Node.JS. Is it possible to edit lines that the cursor is not currently on using Node? I've seen some pretty fancy console graphics out there, though I'm sure most were not written with Node.JS.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is not a feature specific to node.js, but to your terminal. Node can do anything to stdout that you need to manipulate your terminal screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something similar to this with clearLine & cursorTo:

```
process.stdout.write("Something to be replaced");
process.stdout.clearLine();
process.stdout.cursorTo(0);

// continue writing from here...
```

Comment: Did not realize one could specify Y-axis value through cursorTo so I'll mark this as the correct answer! [Here are the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/tty.html#tty_writestream_cursorto_x_y_callback) in case anyone's curious.